# How do I disable regularization for GLMs (PoissonRegressor) in sklearn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, non-linear-regression, poisson

I am fitting models using the PoissonRegressor function in sklearn. However, the code seems to be imposing a un-asked for regularization my model, even when I have set the regularization parameter to 0. Any ideas for how to stop this would be much appreciated!

I have a time varying predictor, x, that is described by a basis set to make a prediction matrix X. I am using X to predict (sparse) count vector Y. My code looks like this:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import PoissonRegressor
PR = PoissonRegressor(alpha = 0.0)
PR.fit(X,Y)
```

However, the resulting fit appear to be smoothed/regularized DESPITE the fact that `alpha = 0`, that is, the regularization is (supposed to be) turned off.

To test this, I copy+pasted the minimization function used in sklearn's GeneralizedLinearRegressor function into my own code and tested it with alpha=0. To avoid a big block of code, this is relegated to the bottom of my question. Using the solver outside of the Regressor object gives DIFFERENT answer than `PR.fit()`, but a nearly identical answer to a solution obtained with statsmodels. This difference is illustrated here.

[image]

Importantly, the sklearn line is much smoother than the version produced by my code/statsmodels, suggesting there is still some sort of regularization happening in the sklearn PoissonRegression function.

My question, then:
How do I disable this (unwanted) regularization?

Thanks!

My code:

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from sklearn._loss.glm_distribution import PoissonDistribution
from sklearn.utils.optimize import _check_optimize_result
from sklearn.linear_model._glm.link import LogLink

alpha = 0

def _safe_lin_pred(X, coef):
    """Compute the linear predictor taking care if intercept is present."""
    if coef.size == X.shape[1] + 1:
        return X @ coef[1:] + coef[0]
    else:
        return X @ coef

def _y_pred_deviance_derivative(coef, X, y, family,link):
    """Compute y_pred and the derivative of the deviance w.r.t coef."""
    lin_pred = _safe_lin_pred(X, coef)
    y_pred = link.inverse(lin_pred)
    d1 = link.inverse_derivative(lin_pred)
    temp = d1 * family.deviance_derivative(y, y_pred)
    if coef.size == X.shape[1] + 1:
        devp = np.concatenate(([temp.sum()], temp @ X))
    else:
        devp = temp @ X  # same as X.T @ temp
    return y_pred, devp

# Same as PoissonRegressor, but with regularization removed. 
def func(coef, X, y,alpha,family,link):
    y_pred, devp = _y_pred_deviance_derivative(
        coef, X, y,family,link
    )
    coef_scaled = alpha * coef
    dev = family.deviance(y, y_pred)
    obj = 0.5 * dev + 0.5 * (coef @ coef_scaled)
    objp = 0.5 * devp 
    objp += coef_scaled
    return obj, objp

args = (X, Y ,alpha,PoissonDistribution(),LogLink())

coef0 = np.ones(X.shape[1])

opt_res = minimize(
    func, coef0, method=method, jac=True,
    options={
        "maxiter": self.max_iter,
        "iprint": (self.verbose > 0) - 1,
        "gtol": self.tol,
        "ftol": 1e3*np.finfo(float).eps,
    },
    args=args)
```

Answer (score 1):

This does not really answer why you observe this regularization despite setting `alpha=0.0`, but a workaround for me was using `GridSearchCV` as it does allow to set this parameter to 0.

Answer (score 0):

The answer turns out to be fairly straightforward: the default tolerance for PoissonRegressor is 1E-4. Changing this (increasing the required fit accuracy) to 1E-5 rectifies this problem.

Why the difference between my code and the sklearn? the sklearn objective function minimizes 1/(2*n_samples)*sum(deviance). As I have a large number of samples, this rescaling changes the effective tolerance of the PoissonRegressor function.